# Issue with ElasticSearch wildcard query and spaces in AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We recently integrated ElasticPress for WooCommerce, and did some improvements to it's code (via it's filters), but hit a few things that appears to be limitations of the ElasticSearch API. We've made mods to the queries sent to the elastic search engine when searching orders, so that the search term works as a partial search (much like the LIKE statement in SQL).

It works fine, except when there are special symbols in the query, like space, or the @ symbol. I've read that this could be avoided by escaping the special characters, but i had no luck doing that either.

I'm using the wildcard query, and i tried replacnig spaces with their escaped version, or even the ? token (which should match any single character). And no luck with that either.

This query works:

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "meta._billing_full_name.value": "*manish*"
    }
}
```

This does too

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "meta._billing_full_name.value": "*kumar*"
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "meta._billing_full_name.value": "*manish k*"
    }
}
```

By the way, we're using AWS ElasticSearch Service as a service provider. They're using an seriously outdated version of ElasticSearch (1.5.3 as far as i know), and i'm not sure if that could be one cause of the problems.

Thanks

Comment: What is the mapping of `meta._billing_full_name.value`. Is it `analyzed string`.

Comment: @Richa i'm not sure. I just installed the plugin, and indexed the site using ElasticPress. I think it doesn't generate any special thing. How should i check what's the mapping of that prop?

Comment: Use `curl -XGET 'http://serverIp:9200/index_name/_mapping/'`

Comment: This seems to be the mapping: [https://paste2.org/09sEeE4D](https://paste2.org/09sEeE4D) (Posting an external link to keep formatting).

Comment: Is this the complete mapping? Seems incomplete

Comment: It's for the field you asked `meta._billing_full_name.value` . Here's the full mapping [https://paste2.org/gf4pzJBs](https://paste2.org/gf4pzJBs)

Comment: @Richa Is there any help you can provide? Thanks for taking the time to help me this far

Comment: Added an answer. See if it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the mapping shown by you `value` seems to be a [multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html). It means it has been indexed both as `analyzed` and `not_analyzed` string.

For `not_analyzed` version of it, use following query:

```
"query": {
"wildcard": {
    "meta._billing_full_name.value.raw": "*manish k*"
  }
}
```

It should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Richa this wasn't the actual implementation i used, but it helped me get in the right direction. I used the `sortable` field instead of `raw` because i wanted to do search in lowercase, and according to my research after your help, that kind of analyzed string works as if it was not_analyzed.